# How can I join an array with a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I created the following array and I want to join this with CTE of a totally different table

```
   CREATE TABLE places (
    name            text,
    labels         text[]
);

INSERT INTO places
    VALUES ('Places',
    ARRAY['store', 'hospital', 'home']);
```

I want to pass these constant values into my  select statement.

```
    SELECT 
        e.address

    FROM env e
```

so It can be like

```
SELECT 
'Cashier.' ||places[1] ||'.'|| e.address,
'Doctor.' ||places[2] || '.'||e.address,
'Wife.' ||places[3] ||'.'||e.address

FROM env e
```

and it will be shown as

```
Cashier.store.NY
Doctor.hospital.DC
Wife.house.CA
```

in the resulting table

I couldn't find anything in the documentation. There are no mutual ids I can join this array on the table with.

I was wondering how this can be done/ or is it even possible or do I have to alter the table and add a column instead of using an array?

Comment: Sorry I really can't understand your question, please update it : you create table "events" and then you insert into table "places" ? What is the table "env" definition, please share its CREATE TABLE statement ? Are 'Cashier', 'Doctor', 'Wife' sql constants, sql tables, ... ?

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: Hey @Edouard , my bad! Updated the question. env is the name I assigned to a table with addresses, and yes those values in my array are sql constants and I want to pass them into my select statement so it can look like

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN`, try something like :

```
SELECT 
'Cashier.' || p.labels[1] ||'.'|| e.address,
'Doctor.' || p.labels[2] || '.'|| e.address,
'Wife.' || p.labels[3] ||'.'|| e.address
FROM env e
CROSS JOIN places AS p
WHERE p.name = 'Places'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

> ```
> CREATE TABLE env (
>     name   varchar(30) primary key,
>     label  text[]
> );
>
> INSERT INTO env (name, label) VALUES
> ('Places', ARRAY['store', 'hospital', 'home']);
>
> CREATE TABLE data (
>     id      serial primary key,
>     address text[]
> );
>
> INSERT INTO data (address) VALUES (ARRAY['store 1', 'hospital 1', 'home 1'])
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, 
> CONCAT_WS('.', 'Cashier', place.label[1], e.address[1]) AS place1,
> CONCAT_WS('.', 'Doctor' , place.label[2], e.address[2]) AS place2,
> CONCAT_WS('.', 'Husband', place.label[3], e.address[3]) AS place3
> FROM data AS e
> JOIN env AS place ON place.name = 'Places'
> ```
>
> ```
> id | place1                | place2                     | place3             
> -: | :-------------------- | :------------------------- | :------------------
>  1 | Cashier.store.store 1 | Doctor.hospital.hospital 1 | Husband.home.home 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5259df50a66f02e233764192cdf9747)*

But it's normally not done via arrays.